# node.js + selenium-webdriver не работает через прокси

Tags: node.js, proxy, selenium

Есть такой код:

```
var util = require("util");

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    proxy = require('selenium-webdriver/proxy'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

  var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
      .setProxy(proxy.manual({http: '113.7.210.74:8909'}))
      .build();

driver.get('https://2ip.ru/');
var  mess_text  = driver.findElement(By.id('copyipaddr'));
mess_text.getText().then(function(text) {console.log(text);});// then
```

Иду через анонимный прокси, но *2IP* всё равно показывает мне мой реальный IP, а не IP прокси. Почему не работает?

Comment: Вот здесь указано как включить proxy для Chrome через args https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481389/selenium-chrome-driver-socks-proxy-configuration

Answer (score 1):

не спец по selenium, но предположу что вы указали прокси для http соединения, а ходите на https

Comment: Возможно вы правы. Ещё вариант,  выборочно в моей сети запрещён https.

Answer (score 1):

Лично мне так и не удалось сделать работу с прокси через вебдрайвер окроме как через браузер phantomJS. На сколько я знаю эта проблема довольно часто встречается.
Скажем так -- селениум отвратно работает с прокси в принципе. Советую или работать с ним через phantomJS где даная фича точно рабочая, или же рассказать какую магию будешь использовать если удасться другим браузером реализовать. =)

Но пробовал я достаточно давно. Может, сейчас что и изменилось...